# Is there any code review tool (similar to FIsheye) for BitBucket without the merge?

Tags: bitbucket

So I understand that once I open a pull request, I automatically get a code review for the code that's about to be merged, that's great! But is there a a way to create a Code review without creating a Pull Request? For example, let's say I am working on a feature and I would like to do a code review with peers, but I don't want to do a Pull Request as the feature is still Work In Progress.

I understand that I can use the **"compare"** feature in BitBucket to see the code diff, but I needed the **"Codereview"** kind of feature explicitly so that I can:

Share the code review link with my peers so that they can see it
They can comment and open "tasks" on the code
and all of it while not creating a Pull Request. Is that possible?

Question is already asked [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Code-review-without-a-pull-request/qaq-p/768604).

Comment: The usual process is to start code review based on a pull-request (this is how I understand the usage in BitBucket). It is acceptable to create the pull-request and mark it as in progress and you can always add more commits on the PR later. Your peers must be aware that you don't need immediate approval but just comments until you finish the feature (PR ready to be merged)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In the current scenario, your suggestion looks good to me. If you put this comment as answer, I'll award you bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual process is to start code review based on a pull-request (this is how I understand the usage in BitBucket).

It is acceptable to create the pull-request and mark it as in progress and you can always add more commits on the PR later.
This is explained in the [official doc](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request):

> But, the pull request is more than just a notification—it’s a dedicated forum for discussing the proposed feature. If there are any problems with the changes, teammates can post feedback in the pull request and even tweak the feature by pushing follow-up commits. All of this activity is tracked directly inside of the pull request.

Your peers must be aware that you don't need immediate approval but just comments until you finish the feature (PR ready to be merged)

Comment: The main use case for us is to do a code review vs one branch, then merge to another.  For example, I am working on (yet unmerged) branch A, and my colleague wants me to review his changes that depend on my work.  We want them to be to request a code review vs branch A, then submit a PR to master *after A is merged*.  Keeping a PR for master open, as the answer suggests, will unnecessarily pollute the code review with code from branch A which is not yet in master.

Comment: @Alex, the review should have A as the target branch, and what you suggest is no problem.  And it can later be edited to target master, when both developers are done.

Comment: @Toby, this still risks a merge, which the developer working on branch A may not appreciate.

Comment: I just experimented the same thing. My long living branch (BR-A) have multiple branches forked by other dev teams and now I have merged my branch into develop, all other PR from BR1, BR2, etc...  to BR-A are now targeted to develop without issues (because BR-A is no more existing).